# How to generate Javadocs for both Java and Kotlin sources together

Tags: maven, javadoc, kotlin-dokka

It seems javadoc maven plugin cannot generate javadocs for Kotlin source code. Thus, I successfully replace it with  Jetbrains Dokka maven plugin. But now Dokka only generates javadocs for Java source code and is missing Kotlin source code.

I have already tried to include `sourceDirectories` and `sourceRoots` in the Jetbrains Dokka maven plugin according to [documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/dokka/1.4.10/user_guide/maven/usage/#configuration-options), but it continues to generate javadocs only for Java source code.

I am using the following configuration in pom.xml:

```xml
<executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>dokka</goal>
                <goal>javadoc</goal>
                <goal>javadocJar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDirectories>
            <source>src/main/java</source>
            <source>src/main/kotlin</source>
        </sourceDirectories>
        <sourceRoots>
            <root>
                <path>src/main/kotlin</path>
                <!-- See platforms section of documentation -->
                <platforms>JVM</platforms>
            </root>
        </sourceRoots>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```